# How to do a `mysqldump` from a remote server with the terminal and save locally

Tags: mysql, terminal

How can I do a `mysqldump` from a server by using the Terminal?

I did the following:

First of all I logged in:

```
ssh root@123.456.78.90  // then I enter my password
```

then I do:

```
mysql->show databases;
```

after that:

```
use the_database;
```

then I do:

```
mysqldump -u myusername -p the_database > db_backup.sql
```

after that, obviously, nothing happens and I do not get an error. So my question is, where does it save the backup and how can I get a the `mysqldump` on my local machine?

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why is it that obvious that nothing happens?

Comment: Sorry, I did choose the wrong words, what I was trying to say is that I visually dont see anything, I mean there is no backup sql file somewhere visible

Comment: If you pipe the output to some file, nothing is printed - if you want to see the output, either skip the pipe or run something like `cat` on the resulting file

Comment: @NicoHaase ok, but I do not understand what you are saying

Comment: If you use `>` in a command line, you redirect the output (here: the dumped data) to a file - that's why you see no output

Comment: ah ok yes, but when I enter `> /Users/myusername/Desktop/somefolder/db_backup.sql` there is no output either :-/

Comment: What do you mean by "output"? To any file? Keep in mind that this redirection does not work across different systems - if you run `mysqldump > somefile.sql`, that file is stored on the server which you are using

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of how and where to backup, but most probably you would not like to store your backup in the same server where you are running the database.

If you have ssh access to the server you could create an ssh-tunnel, the most basic example of this could be:

```
$ ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 root@123.456.78.90
```

What this will do is to open port `3307` locally (just in case you already are using `3306`) and forward it to  `localhost:3306` going through `123.456.78.90`

Then you could do something like:

```
$ mysqldump -h localhost -P 3307 -u myusername -p the_database > db_backup.sql
```

To know your current path, run [`pwd`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pwd) it will print your current directory and in where the `db_backup.sql` will be created in case you don't specify and absolute path.

Without using ssh you could also try to connect directly by just specifying the host:

```
$ mysqldump -h 123.456.78.90 -u myusername -p the_database > db_backup.sql
```

In case the port is open probably you will need just to modify/grant the user permissions to allow your IP to access:

```
 mysql> GRANT ALL ON the_database.* TO your_user@'123.456.78.90' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';
```

Comment: ah ok, so `pwd` I should enter something like `User/myusername/Desktop/somefolder/` ?

Comment: you can fully ignore the `pwd` command, is just for you to use it as a reference and to know where probably the files will be stored, for example, if you want your backup to be in `/tmp/db_backup.sql` you could use `myqldump -h localhost -P 3307 -u myusername -p the_database > /tmp/db_backup.sql`, if you don't specify an absolute path the files will be stored in the current directory, normally the output of the `pwd` command

Comment: ok, should I then create the tunnel after I entered the `mysql` command (see above in the question)? sorry, pretty new to this :-)

Comment: Depends if the port is accessible and if your user permissions in the DB, you could either try to connect directly without the ssh tunnel and if that doesn't work a try, create the tunnel and then try the `mysqldump`

Comment: OK, either or, nothing happens :-s

Comment: if using ssh to create the tunnel, check if the port is being forwarded by doing something like:  `nc -vt localhost 3307` (in case you are using port `3307`)

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your server using ssh command.

run below code

```
mysqldump -u userName -p databaseName > /path/to/backup.sql
```

the location path must be on same server